# не срабатывает rotate()

Tags: css

```css
p > span{
transform: rotate(20deg)
}
```

```html
<p>Получите скидку <span>30%</span> на мойку окон</p>
```

не переворачивается

Comment: задайте для `span` `display:inline-block`. `inline` элементы не трансформируются.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте `display: inline-block`:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}
```

```html
<p>Получите скидку <span>30%</span> на мойку окон</p>
```

[Тут сказано, что объект должен быть `inline-block` или иметь другие свойства...](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transformable-element)

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Comment: @Proshka, пожалуйста:)